# hacer MIN() y MAX() doble con un rango de una sección establecida SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Mi problema se plantea de esta manera: Poseo una tabla con todas las marcaciones de los empleados, estas poseen los parámetros de nombre, hora(marcacion) y fecha, todos estos datos se almacenan en forma de lista.

ejemplo

```
Nombre      Hora            fecha
JULIO PEREZ 05:47:46 a. m.  1/6/2020
JULIO PEREZ 09:40:46 a. m.  1/6/2020
JULIO PEREZ 11:33:06 a. m.  1/6/2020
JULIO PEREZ 11:46:46 a. m.  1/6/2020
JULIO PEREZ 11:46:59 a. m.  1/6/2020
JULIO PEREZ 02:46:59 p. m.  1/6/2020
JULIO PEREZ 05:42:42 p. m.  1/6/2020
```

Mi objetivo es tomar las marcaciones de la hora de entrada de trabajo, hora de salida del trabajo, hora de inicio de almuerzo y hora de fin de almuerzo de forma lineal.

He podido lograr la entrada y salida con el uso del `MIN()` y `MAX()` ya que los empleados trabajo en de 5am a 6pm y sus marcaciones se encuentran dentro de ese rango, entonces para sacar esos todos simplemente hago un GROUP BY nombre,fecha  y `MIN(hora)`, `MAX(hora)` con esto tengo:

```
Nombre       fecha       Hora de entrada      hora de salida
JULIO PEREZ  1/6/2020     05:47:46 a. m.      05:42:42 p. m.
```

Pero el problema es que también necesito sacar sus hora de almuerzo que tienen un rango entre 11am y 1pm;

Entonces seria posible sacar un `MIN(hora)` y `MAX(hora)` con un rango establecido de 11am y 1pm siempre en la misma consulta (no se podría hacer otro consulta utilizando los rangos 11am y 1pm ya que hay empleados que no marcan sus horas de almuerzo y esto cambiaría de tamaños los tablas que generarían las dos consultas y no cuadrarían) y también las horas de marcas no son exactamente 4 ya que también hay marcas "muertas" estas no se toman en cuenta horas como 2pm, 4:55pm, etc.

En forma gráfica quiero hacer esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para poder tener esto :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
select 

NombreCompleto as 'Nombre Completo',
Fecha,

MIN(Hora) as 'Hora De Entrada',

??????? as 'Hora De Inicio almuerzo',
??????? as 'Hora De Salida almuerzo',

MAX(Hora) as 'Hora De Salida'

from

Marcas 

where  NombreCompleto = 'JULIO PEREZ'

GROUP BY

NombreCompleto,
Fecha
```

Comment: Según entiendo tu problema radica en que tienes las horas de marcación pero no sabes a que corresponden, es decir, si es inicio almuerzo o fin de almuerzo ¿es correcto?.

Comment: No, lo que necesito es sacar un min() y max de con un rango de 11:00am y 1:00pm, ya que en este rango de horas los empleados salen ha almorzar y con esto para sacar el inicio del almuerzo seria el min() con este rango y su finalizacion del almuerzo seria el max() con el mismo rango (11:00am y 1:00pm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma bastante sencilla es verificar las horas con el rango predefinido de lo que se considera horario de almuerzo. Algo así:

```
SELECT Nombre,
       MIN(CASE WHEN Mediodia.Desde IS NULL THEN Hora ELSE NULL END)     as 'Entrada',
       MIN(CASE WHEN Mediodia.Desde IS NOT NULL THEN Hora ELSE NULL END) as 'SalidaAlmuerzo',
       MAX(CASE WHEN Mediodia.Desde IS NOT NULL THEN Hora ELSE NULL END) as 'EntradaAlmuerzo',
       MAX(CASE WHEN Mediodia.Desde IS NULL THEN Hora ELSE NULL END)     as 'Salida'
       FROM Marcas M
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT '11:00:00 am' AS Desde,
                         '15:00:00 pm' AS Hasta
                  ) Mediodia
                  ON M.Hora BETWEEN Mediodia.Desde AND Mediodia.Hasta
       GROUP BY M.Nombre
```

Luego simplemente es hacer las funciones de agregación condicionales a si la hora entra en el rango del almuerzo o no.

Comment: Lo probare ahora mismo gracias.

Comment: A funcionada muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Primero, tendrás que hacer el cálculo de la diferencia entre las horas y la franja de tiempo. Esto se puede hacer con la función `DATEDIFF`.

```
-- En caso de la primera franja de 11AM a 1PM
SELECT Hora FROM Marcas
   WHERE (DATEDIFF(hour, Hora, '11:00:00')) <= 0
   AND (DATEDIFF(hour, Hora, '13:00:00')) >= 0
```

Una vez tenemos la *query*, debemos integrarla como *subquery* en el `SELECT`.
A esa misma *subquery*, vamos a aplicarle el `MAX` para la salida del almuerzo y el `MIN` para el inicio del almuerzo.

```
SELECT
  NombreCompleto AS 'Nombre completo',
  Fecha,
  MIN(Hora) AS 'Hora de entrada',

  (SELECT MIN(Hora) FROM Marcas subq
    WHERE subq.NombreCompleto = Marcas.NombreCompleto AND -- Filtramos el grupo
    subq.Fecha = Marcas.Fecha AND
    DATEDIFF(hour, Hora, '11:00:00') <= 0 AND
    DATEDIFF(hour, Hora, '13:00:00') >= 0) AS 'Hora de inicio almuerzo',

  (SELECT MAX(Hora) FROM Marcas subq
    WHERE subq.NombreCompleto = Marcas.NombreCompleto AND -- Filtramos el grupo
    subq.Fecha = Marcas.Fecha AND
    DATEDIFF(hour, Hora, '11:00:00') <= 0 AND
    DATEDIFF(hour, Hora, '13:00:00') >= 0) AS 'Hora de salida almuerzo',

  MAX(Hora) AS 'Hora de salida'

FROM Marcas
GROUP BY NombreCompleto, Fecha
```

Estoy convencido de que hay una forma más elegante de conseguir esto. Hay bastanta *query* duplicada. Quizás con una *view*...

Espero que sirva.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, lo probare.